# Identify LEGO branded forklift piece

Tags: part-identification

Can you help me identify this forklift type piece of LEGO branded plastic? I can't really call it a brick, though it does clutch onto two standard studs.

[image]

[image]

Comment: It looks like you are missing the spring.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That would be [Vehicle, Forklift 2 x 2 Plate and Yellow Fork (Complete Assembly)](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3430c02#T=C&C=11), but it is broken.

For future reference, searching for 'Forklift' in the 'Parts' category on BrickLink gave [this result](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogList.asp?catType=P&catID=&itemYear=&searchName=Y&searchNo=Y&q=forklift&catLike=W). From there finding the proper part was a matter of looking at the images.